# reconstructed world position from depth is wrong

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement deferred shading/lighting. In order to reduce the number/size of the buffers I use I wanted to use the depth texture to reconstruct world position later on.

I do this by multiplying the pixel's coordinates with the inverse of the projection matrix and the inverse of the camera matrix. This sort of works, but the position is a bit off. Here's the absolute difference with a sampled world position texture:

[image]

For reference, this is the code I use in the second pass fragment shader:

```
vec2 screenPosition_texture = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x)/WIDTH, (gl_FragCoord.y)/HEIGHT);
float pixelDepth = texture2D(depth, screenPosition_texture).x;

vec4 worldPosition = pMatInverse*vec4(VertexIn.position, pixelDepth, 1.0);
worldPosition = vec4(worldPosition.xyz/worldPosition.w, 1.0);
//worldPosition /= 1.85;
worldPosition = cMatInverse*worldPosition_byDepth;
```

If I uncomment worldPosition /= 1.85, the position is reconstructed a lot better (on my geometry/range of depth values). I just got this value by messing around after comparing my output with what it should be (stored in a third texture).

I'm using 0.1 near, 100.0 far and my geometries are up to about 15 away.
I know there may be precision errors, but this seems a bit too big of an error too close to the camera.
Did I miss anything here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate clipspace.w from clipspace.xyz and (inv) projection matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523588/calculate-clipspace-w-from-clipspace-xyz-and-inv-projection-matrix)

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I didn't transform my depth after fetching it from the buffer. Never knew about about the depth conversion from ndcspace. pixelDepth=pixelDepth*2.0-1.0; did the trick :)

Edit: now how do I mark it as answered?

Comment: You've to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment:
I didn't convert the depth value from NDC space to clip space.
I should have added this line:

```
pixelDepth = pixelDepth * 2.0 - 1.0;
```